# What are parties in a legal dispute called (collectively)?

Tags: phrase-request

Is it 'dispute sides' or something? How to say it, I forgot.

Comment: I suggest "the parties in a case / lawsuit / conflict".

Comment: They're litigants.

Comment: In the UK, they are generally called 'parties', but they can be further identified, e.g. civil cases will have a claimant and a respondent. In County Court civil cases the claimant used to be called the 'plaintiff' before 1999.